# Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'TodoItemNode[]'

Tags: rxjs, angular-material2

I am trying to use Mat-tree module in my angular application, but getting compile time error:

> Argument of type '(node: TodoItemNode) => TodoItemNode[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(node: TodoItemNode) => Observable'. Type 'TodoItemNode[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'TodoItemNode[]'

Here is the link from where I have referred or copied the code for demo UI:

[Angular Material Official Mat-Tree Example Link](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

Here is the code where it throws an error:

Login Report Component:

```
constructor(
    private database: ChecklistDatabase
  ) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel,
    this.isExpandable, this.getChildren);  // This line
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

    database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }
```

Edit:

```
 transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode = existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  }
```

And

```
 getLevel = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.level;

 isExpandable = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

 getChildren = (node: TodoItemNode): TodoItemNode[] => node.children;
```

`MatTreeFlattener` Constructor:

```
constructor(transformFunction: (node: T, level: number) => F, getLevel: (node: F) => number, isExpandable: (node: F) => boolean, getChildren: (node: T) => Observable<T[]>);
```

Package.Json

```
{
  "name": "kalpavriksha-angular-v4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/filesaver": "0.0.30",
    "angular-chat": "^1.0.9",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-file-picker": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.11.0",
    "cloudboost": "^2.0.264",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.4.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.3",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.2.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "4.6.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "md-date-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "ng-chat": "^1.0.12",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.3.1",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.0.27",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-inactivity": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.7",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-progress-bar": "0.0.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: That a problem somewhere in your code, not in npm packages

Comment: Let me share the block of code where it throws an error

Comment: @PrashantPimpale And where's your code? It's been about 50+ minutes.

Comment: @Edric sorry! updated.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Could you also add what `transformer`, `getLevel`, `isExpandable` and `getChildren` are?

Comment: @Edric updated!

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same Error for [MAT-TREE](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview)

> Solved by updating the Angular Material @ package.json and Delete the Node Modules and npm install.

```
From "@angular/material": "^6.2.0" to=>  "@angular/material": "^6.4.2"
```